# Does request_terminate_timeout overwrite max_execution_time?

Tags: php

Does the `request_terminate_timeout` in the PHP-FPM Pool Definitions overwrite the `max_execution_time` in php.ini file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently the're both doing the same thing at different levels.
max_execution_time is honored by PHP itself and request_terminate_timeout is handled by the FPM process control mechanism.
So whichever is set to the lowest value will kick in first.
Also Apache has the idle-timeout parameter that it observes and will give up on the PHP process after that time.

Also

> maximum execution time is not affected by system calls, stream operations etc.

so you need to take that into account as well.